# Python Logging -- Accessing Data within Requests Log

Tags: python-2.7, logging, python-requests

I'm trying to access the data within the logs that are printed. Here's how to set up logging:

```
import logging
import httplib as http_client
http_client.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1

#Initialize Logging

logging.basicConfig() 
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
requests_log = logging.getLogger("requests.packages.urllib3")
requests_log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
requests_log.propagate = True
```

When I make an HTTP request using Python Requests,

```
r = requests.get(api+'download?name=XXXX),headers=header)
```

it prints out a bunch of lines of log. This is the one I'm interested in:

```
header: Location: http://09.bm-data-api.prod.XXXXXXX.net/download/XXXXX
```

How do I pass this header info back into a variable to use?

Thanks
Dave

Answer (score 0):

The value you need has been logged (presumably to a file). So you'll need to read the contents of the logfile, find the line(s) you're interested in and perform the necessary work that you wish to do. You can read a file with:

```
with open(myfile) as f:
    data = f.readlines()
```

and you can then iterate over `data` to find the lines that you're interested in.